# Store diff of files in PHP

Tags: php, diff, versioning

When saving `revision #7` of a textfile with PHP, I use:

```
<?php 
  $file = fopen("data/myfile-revision7", 'w');
  fwrite($file, $data);
  fclose($file);
?>
```

But instead of saving the whole `$data` again and again for every revision, I would prefer to store the **differences** between `myfile-revision1` and `myfile-revision7`.

Is there a function *included in PHP* that would compute the diff of 2 text files?

---

*Note: If later, I want to get the full `myfile-revision7` textfile again, how can I generate this file back, with the diff data?*

Comment: perhaps you could make use of the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to filter out the text which is already saved elsewhere. and put the remaining text in a new file.

Comment: have you looked into xdiff? http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xdiff.php

Comment: You are basically asking for a tool recommendation here, making this off-topic.  You might google `PHP diff library` and see what turns up (like `xdiff` perhaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `xdiff_file_diff` function. Here is the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-diff.php).

```
<?php
  $old = 'data/myfile-revision1';
  $new = 'data/myfile-revision7';
  $output = 'data/rev-1-7.diff'

  xdiff_file_diff($old, $new, $output);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I cannot use `xdiff_file_diff` because I cannot install `libxdiff` on my shared hosting (I'm not root)... Do you see another solution ?

Comment: I think you can read two files and then take diff using external library like this: [http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php](http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php). Or, you can make system call `exec('diff revision1 revision2 > rev-1-7.diff')` if your shared hosting allows it.

Comment: I think it seems to work with `<?php
$diff = exec('diff filea fileb'); echo $diff;
?>`
But I have this answer :  `\ No newline at end of file` : any idea ?

Comment: Try to write a file with `implode("\r\n", $diff)`.

Comment: the standard `diff` / `patch` Linux tools finally won't work for my usage, because they are designed for diff **between lines**... But I only have one big line containing lots of text data... not lines... Another kind of `diff` in mind for this ?